# php mysql - select table starting with underscore

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do you get a table that starts with an underscore?

This works for getting all tables that start with a capital T:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'T%'
```

This doesn't work (returns all tables):

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '_%'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the underscore is a wildcard, you need to escape it to match the underscore itself:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '\_%'
```

From [MySQL.com - 3.3.4.7 Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html):

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use “_” to match any single
>   character and “%” to match an arbitrary number of characters
>   (including zero characters)

Answer (score 1):

The underscore is a wildcard in sql LIKE statements and stand for 1 of any character :)

Use like `SHOW TABLES LIKE '___ADMIN'` to get anything like SYSADMIN or ORGADMIN but not ADMIN or FOOBARADMIN.

To list all tables that start with an underscore you need to escape it.

`SHOW TABLES LIKE '\_%'`

Comment: Got ya. I need all forums that start with the character "_" - all characters after that could be anything, so I can't use something like "show tables like 'specificword'"

Comment: Is there someway to escape that wildcard to interpret it as a character?

Comment: Yes with the backslash by default.

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
mysql > SHOW TABLES LIKE '\_%';
```

Because as the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html) states:

> To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by
>   the escape character. If you do not specify the ESCAPE character, “\”
>   is assumed.